# How do I structure a wordpress plugin to pull data from a custom database to display as posts?

Tags: wordpress

I have a database of structured data I want to display in wordpress as posts. I could import them into the wordpress database but then I would have to keep that mirror of the data in sync with the master database which would add all sorts of complications.

I haven't been able to find the right action hooks to override the db they are pulled from and the custom post type functionality sounds like what I want but seems to only make sense when pulling from the wordpress database.

I could just use custom template tags to display my data, but those posts would still be pulled from the wordpress db.

I've looked at some real estate listing plugins and sports team management plugins for wordpress as that seems like a similar problem, even though I'm not dealing with real estate listings or sports teams but they still store the information in the wordpress db.

Beyond forking wordpress to mess with the post and query classes which seems like rabbit hole i don't want to go down what are my options? Other plugins solving the same problem would also be useful.

I'm new to wordpress development but not web development.

edit: I would be acceptable but not ideal to have the custom data in the same db as wordpress if that's necessary or makes things simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You can create tables within WordPress and interact with those tables like you would any other database tables. WP ships with a number of helpful functions to save you time. To install the initial table, you want to use the `dbdelta` function. The codex gives this as an example:

```
global $jal_db_version;
$jal_db_version = "1.0";

function jal_install() {
   global $jal_db_version;

   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "liveshoutbox";

   $sql = "CREATE TABLE " . $table_name . " (
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
      name tinytext NOT NULL,
      text text NOT NULL,
      url VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY id (id)
    );";

   require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
   dbDelta($sql);

   add_option("jal_db_version", $jal_db_version);
}

function jal_install_data() {
      $welcome_name = "Mr. Wordpress";
      $welcome_text = "Congratulations, you just completed the installation!";

      $rows_affected = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array( 'time' => current_time('mysql'), 'name' => $welcome_name, 'text' => $welcome_text ) );
}
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins for more.

Next, to any of your CRUD functions, you'll want to use the WP_Query class. The codex does a wonderful job explaining how each of these functions work: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query.

I would recommend developing your plugin with Custom Post Type functionality if at all possible. If you do so, it will just work better with WP, other plugins will work better with it, and it will be easier for users to understand how to manipulate your plugin. There was a great document in the codex that addressed not unnecessarily creating more tables in the WP database, but I cannot seem to find it. Maybe someone else can point you toward it.

Comment: I won't be creating any tables with this plugin, I'm just resigned to the fact that the wordpress database will have to live in my production database with a prefix.

Thanks for the +1 to Custom Post Type, it looks like this is what I need to do so other WP functionality and plugins will work with it. CRUD won't be an issue since this data is managed outside of wordpress.

Comment: @Freshawk - sorry for the misunderstanding. I'd still be interested in getting a better understanding for the issue and discussing some possibilities.

Comment: So I have a database of real estate listings, CRUD operations are all managed outside of wordpress by an existing system ("the manager"). What I want to do is to display those listings in a blog format with wordpress. It would be fantastic if the search/tagging/etc. features of wordpress worked for these real estate "posts".

Comment: I can't import the data into wordpress as when CRUD operations are made in the manager they need to be reflected in wordpress immediately and I don't want to deal with that ugly sync problem anyway.

Comment: I would ideally like to have the wordpress database separate from the existing manager DB but I'm pretty sure that's either not possible or overly complex.

Comment: (It's not actually real estate listings but it's the same problem and hypotheticals don't require approval from execs to talk about online).

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: If the original data is posted somewhere, I would use WP's HTTP API (http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) or the built in feed functions (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) to retrieve that data. That way all you are doing is displaying the data, which is managed elsewhere.

Comment: What benefit would I get from using wordpress at all in that case?

Is it really not possible or common for people to want to create post objects in wordpress out of their existing databases?